# Entity Framework adding item to ICollection error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two simple classes, `User` and `Task`:

```
class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

The Task class has a property `Followers` which is an `ICollection<User>`

Here is the db context class:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
        {
            mb.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.UserId); 
            mb.Entity<Task>().HasKey(t => t.TaskId);
        }
    }
```

and here is the code in the Main program:

```
var db = new MyContext();

var user = new User();
user.Name = "John Doe";
user.Email = "jd@email.com";
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();

var follower = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "John Doe").FirstOrDefault();

var task = new Task();
task.Name = "Make the tea";
task.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
task.Followers.Add(follower);  // ERROR

db.Tasks.Add(task);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The trouble is I am getting an error when trying to add the follower to the task.

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Icollection` is an interface, change it to a `list`.

Comment: @Ofiris see this post for an example - `ICollection` is the recommended implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439425/ef4-1-poco-why-should-i-use-icollection

Comment: What's relationship between user and task?? is it one to many?

Comment: see my answer. it may initialization problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `Followers` collection is null. Instead of newing up your classes, let EF [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) them for you ...

```
var user = db.Users.Create();
```

and

```
var task = db.Tasks.Create();
```

---

If you're still getting problems then your proxies are not being created. You can initialise the collections in the class constructors, make each of them a `HashSet<T>`. It would be better though to identify why the proxies are not getting generated ...

```
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
       Followers = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I changed them to Create but that doesn't seem to solve the problem - still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it always a `HashSet` that EF wants or is it irrelevant what type of `ICollection`  the collections are?

Comment: btw, for other users coming here and have to implement the workaround, the reason is perhaps described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069563/why-is-my-entity-framework-code-first-proxy-collection-null-and-why-cant-i-set)

Comment: @Default I believe it's irrelevant. We use an in-house implementation of `ICollection`

Answer (score 4):

try this. just initialize `Follower`

```
var db = new MyContext();

var user = new User();
user.Name = "John Doe";
user.Email = "jd@email.com";
db.Users.Add(user);
db.SaveChanges();

var follower = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == "John Doe").FirstOrDefault();

var task = new Task();
task.Name = "Make the tea";
task.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
task.Followers =  new Collection<User>()
task.Followers.Add(follower);

db.Tasks.Add(task);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will have to chan ge the constructor as mentioned by qujck

```
        var db = new MyContext();

        var user = new User();
        user.Name = "John Doe";
        user.Email = "jd@email.com";

        var task = new Task();
        task.Name = "Make the tea";
        task.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        task.Followers.Add(user);
        db.Tasks.Add(task);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the List, because ICollection is an interface then it can't be initialized, but List can be (the following worked for me)

Instead of:

```
task.Followers.Add(follower);
```

Write:

```
task.Followers= new List<User>();
task.Followers.Add(follower);
```

This should solve your problem :)